# Where should Salesforce My domain created first? sandbox or production

Tags: salesforce, sandbox

I need to create My Domain in salesforce. What will be the correct procedure to create it? either we have to create a My Domain in production environment first or can we create it first in sandbox and test it?

In the below link, it was told to reserve the My Domain in production first and then to create in sandbox.

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008qILIAY

Is there any drawbacks in creating and deploying the My Domain in sandbox environment first?

Thanks in advance.

Dinesh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically it doesn't matter, however, it is possible that another customer has used the same "My Domain" name in your sandbox even if it is available in your production.  (Sandbox instances don't correlate with production ones.)
I'd create it in Production first, then refresh your sandbox.